# Add Footer Text to All Slides in Beamer

Tags: beamer, header-footer

Is there a way to append footer text to the slides in beamer? I wanted to get rid of the default footer, but I want to add a bit of additional text. Right now I have:

```
%gets rid of bottom navigation bars
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]{}

%gets rid of navigation symbols
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[Section **8.2.1 The Headline and Footline** of the `beameruserguide`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) lists the predefined inserts that can be used to add information to the `footline` template. If you want to add some additional information (not covered by the listed inserts), you can use the `text line` option for the footline template.

A little example in which "some text" is added as well as the short name of the author centered and the page number flushed to the right (I used a `\parbox` with some negative vertical skip to shift the information a little bit upwards):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[text line]{%
  \parbox{\linewidth}{\vspace*{-8pt}some text\hfill\insertshortauthor\hfill\insertpagenumber}}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\author[JD]{John Doe}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason, if you parametrise all the elements of the footline (so you do not have the "some text" bit but e.g. \insertshorttitle), then only the first element is shifted upwards by the vspace. Any idea how to generalise your command for these cases? I have not managed to do it myself.

Answer (score 9):

I can think of only one problem that the solution proposed by @GonzaloMedina has: when the slides number goes from `9` to `10` then there is a horizontal jump in the footline. The following solves the problem by putting each component of the footline in its own box:

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[text line]{%
  \parbox{0.8\linewidth}{
    \vspace*{-8pt}\insertshorttitle~(\insertshortauthor)
  }
  \hfill%
  \parbox{0.15\linewidth}{
    \vspace*{-8pt}\raggedleft\insertpagenumber
  }
}
```

Comment: but the page numbering starts from the title page. how to make the numbering start from the slide after the title page?
and the ability to create a bar or some box around the footnotes would be excellent