# Footer in Beamer

Tags: beamer, formatting, header-footer

I found in this related topic [Add Footer Text to All Slides in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26476/add-footer-text-to-all-slides-in-beamer) a nice code for footer in `beamer` with the `Frankfurt` theme.

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[text line]{%
\parbox{\linewidth}{\vspace*{-8pt}some text\hfill\insertshortauthor\hfill\insertpagenumber}}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
```

That is exactly what I need. But when I add it to my presentation I lost default "navigation" icons.

So my questions are:

- Is it possible to have footer with these icons?
- How to change background color of this footer?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I wasn't sure if the navigation symbols should be part of the `footline`; in my answer I placed them outside the `footline`, but let me know if you want some changes to be made.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case, I propose you a more sophisticated definition for the `footline` template:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\newcommand\mytext{some text}

\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
  \mytext
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\hfill\insertpagenumber
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatletter

\author[JD]{John Doe}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used two `beamercolorbox`es (one for the additional text, the other one for the short author and page number) to give you the possibility to customize each one separately, but of course, you could only use one and distribute the information to suit your needs.

To change the color used for the `beamerbox`es, set a `beamer` color and then use it in the mandatory argument for `beamercolorbox`; for example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\setbeamercolor{footlinecolor}{bg=black!70,fg=white}

\newcommand\mytext{some text}

\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm]{footlinecolor}%
  \mytext
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{footlinecolor}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\hfill\insertpagenumber
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatletter

\author[JD]{John Doe}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you - that is exactly what I need. Could you only tell me how to change color of your footer? I tried \setbeamercolor{footlinecolor}{bg=black!70} but it doesn't work. I have also defined \setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=brown, bg=black!70} so I don't know why it doesn't work...

Comment: @astrak You're welcome. Regarding the color issue, you were almost there: after setting the color, you use the name in the mandatory argument of the `beamercolorbox` environment; see my updated answer for a complete example.