# Beamer frame and titleframe template

Tags: beamer, header-footer, templates, frame-title

I have been looking through a lot of questions and their relative answers to solve this, but could not quite find the help I need. I want to create a Beamer template for my frames and my title frame, eventually derivated from the [Goettingen theme](https://ctan.tetaneutral.net/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) (p. 150, CTAN documentation).

I tried [creating my own `.sty` files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146529/design-a-custom-beamer-theme-from-scratch), [defining and redefining the commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238580/redefine-beamer-frame-environment), [working with the head- and footlines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105613/footer-in-beamer), etc. but could not manage to get exactly what I want, and I'm getting lost in all the possibilities. The closest MWE I got so far is the following :

```
\documentclass[french]{beamer}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%PACKAGES%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx}                                  %pictures, graphs, tikz elts
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,plotmarks,3d,patterns}
\graphicspath{{./Medias/}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%DATA%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%

\logo{\includegraphics[width=0.1\paperwidth]{LOGO.PNG}}
\title[Short title]{Main Title}
\subtitle{This long subtitle might need to be displayed on several lines sometimes.}
\author{\textsc{Name} Surname\inst{1,2}}
%\author[1]{\textsc{Super} Visor 1\inst{1}}\\
%\author[2]{\textsc{Super} Visor 2\inst{2}}
\date{\today}


\institute{
    \inst{1}
    Uni for Students\\
    University
    \and
    \inst{2}
    Place for work\\
    Start-up
}

\usetheme[hideothersubsections,right]{Goettingen}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%FRAMES%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
    \begin{flushleft}
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=1cm]{logo}
            \insertlogo\par
        \end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{flushleft}
    \vbox{}
    \vfill
    \begingroup
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=4pt,center]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
  \endgroup
  \vfill
}
\makeatother



\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{
    \begin{flushleft}
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=1cm]{logo}
            \insertlogo\par
        \end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{flushleft}
    \hspace{2pt}
    }
\makeatother



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%START DOCUMENT%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame} 
\frametitle{There Is No Largest Prime Number} 
\framesubtitle{The proof uses \textit{reductio ad absurdum}.} 
\begin{theorem}
There is no largest prime number. \end{theorem} 
\begin{enumerate} 
\item<1-| alert@1> Suppose $p$ were the largest prime number. 
\item<2-> Let $q$ be the product of the first $p$ numbers. 
\item<3-> Then $q+1$ is not divisible by any of them. 
\item<1-> But $q + 1$ is greater than $1$, thus divisible by some prime
number not in the first $p$ numbers.
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

So far, it gives me these frames :

[image: Title Frame]
and
[image: Frame]

But I'm looking for something like this (.ppt made) :

[image: Title Frame ok]
and
[image: Frame ok]

So, for now, I could not manage to get the headline to accept the logo and the supervisors' names vertically centered, and I would love to be able to customize the foot- and headline like I did in a `report` document, i.e. with :

```
\lhead{\insertlogo} 
\chead{\bfseries Title}
\rhead{ \textsl{Report}} 
\lfoot{YXX} 
\cfoot{\bfseries \textsl {\small \textcolor{Red1}{\fbox{IMPORTANT THING HERE}}}}
\rfoot{\thepage}
```

Thank you for any help you could provide, it is much appreciated.

Comment: Please don't mix multiple unrelated problems in a single post. A custom headline does not really have any connection to changing the colours in the sidebar.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz : I must admit I'm totally lost and do not know where to approach all of this from. I'm truly sorry if the post does not fit one or multiple forum's rules. I am just looking for several ways or methods to get the presentation to look how it should.

Comment: I suggest to google for https://www.google.com/search?q=beamer+tutorial+filetype%3Apdf. There are several, of about 30-50 pages, introducing into the standards. // If you want to design from scratch I suggest reading and trying https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2016/12/07/how-to-make-a-presentation-in-latex/ .

Comment: @MS-SPO thank you ! This is indeed very helpful. I hope that I will be able to get everything right in time, and I keep it pinned for now