# Frame-numbering alignment in beamer with many slides

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, page-numbering

Using beamer with wuerzburg outer and chamfered inner theme I created a long presentation with 100+ slides. After 9 slides the frame numbers *are not correctly aligned*, the total framenumber is visible but the current framenumber is above it, and I did not find a way to correctly align it.

In the MWE on the last 30 frames tried the solution here: [Add Footer Text to All Slides in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26476/add-footer-text-to-all-slides-in-beamer) but this one removes the original footline background (colortheme).
If you uncomment the `\usecolortheme{shark}` it is more visible why the current framenumber disappears.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<beamer>{
    \useoutertheme[glossy]{wuerzburg}
    \useinnertheme[shadow,outline]{chamfered}
    \usecolortheme{shark}
}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Original footline}
\blindtext[100]
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[text line]{%
  \parbox{\linewidth}{\vspace*{-8pt}some text\hfill\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}
}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Different footline}
\blindtext[50]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the Würzburg theme available somewhere? I cannot reproduce the problem with the default theme.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use https://github.com/pmagwene/beamer-theme-collection/blob/master/beamerouterthemewuerzburg.sty you could change the footline definition like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme[glossy]{wuerzburg}
\useinnertheme[shadow,outline]{chamfered}
\usecolortheme{shark}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \ifbeamer@wuerzburg@nofootline
  \else
  \leavevmode%
  \pgfuseshading{beamer@bottomshade}
  \ifbeamer@wuerzburg@glossy%
    \pgfuseshading{beamer@headfootshade}
    \vskip-3.5ex
    \hbox{%
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.8\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,left,ignorebg]{headfoot}%
        \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}%
        \hspace*{3.5ex}%
        \insertshortauthor{}%
        \beamerwuerzburgthemeadddelimiter{\insertshortinstitute}%
        \beamerwuerzburgthemeadddelimiter{\insertshortdate}%
      \end{beamercolorbox}%
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.2\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right,ignorebg]{headfoot}%
        \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}%
        \insertframenumber{} / \if\thelastframecounter0\inserttotalframenumber\else\thelastframecounter\fi \hspace*{3.5ex}
      \end{beamercolorbox}}
  \else%
    \hbox{%
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.8\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,left]{headfoot}%
        \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}%
        \hspace*{3.5ex}%
        \insertshortauthor{}%
        \beamerwuerzburgthemeadddelimiter{\insertshortinstitute}%
        \beamerwuerzburgthemeadddelimiter{\insertshortdate}%
      \end{beamercolorbox}%
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.2\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{headfoot}%
        \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}%
        \insertframenumber{} / \if\thelastframecounter0\inserttotalframenumber\else\thelastframecounter\fi \hspace*{3.5ex}
      \end{beamercolorbox}}
    \fi%
  \vskip0pt%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Original footline}
\blindtext[100]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]